# How can I extract a string from a text file and rename a file with it?

Tags: powershell, pdf, command-line

For the project I am working on I have thousands of forms (.pdf) that I need to rename using the contents within the forms.

So far, I have run OCR on them and exported the content to text files. Each PDF form has a .txt file of the same name containing all its information. I would like to use powershell (if possible) to extract a specific part of the text file to rename the PDF file, but I am not sure how I can do that.

To give a better idea of what I'm working on, the form contained in the pdf and the text files (ex-12345.pdf and 12345.txt) looks something like this-

~~~

constituency: xxxyyyzzz

polling station: abc def ghi (001)

stream: 123

~~~

What I need to do is to extract the polling station name and rename the pdf file to that.

"12345.pdf" -> "abc_def_ghi_(001).pdf"

So I need to figure out how to extract the string between "station:" and "stream:" from 12345.txt. But to make things a bit more complicated, the text files I want to extract the string from have some irregularities when it comes to spacing.

for example, the previous form may look like this in the text file-

~~~

constit uency: xxxyyyzzz

polling stat i on: abc de f  ghi (00 1)

s tream: 12 3

~~~

Fortunately, the letters themselves seem to be intact.

So, I would like to learn how to extract the string containing the polling station name from these text files and rename the corresponding pdf files with it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: PDF is not convertible to txt, OCR (optical character recognition) is indeed the only solution but not stable in a lot of scenario's, programming around this instability is a tough job, find something that is consistent you might be able to use that in a regex or some kind of string manipulation like the ':' character after station or try replacing spaces with nothing, will post an answer with code you can use in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

```
'polling station: abc def ghi (001)' |
  Select-String ' station: (.+)' |
  ForEach-Object { "{0}.pdf" -f ($_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value -replace ' ','_') }
# outputs 'abc_def_ghi_(001).pdf'
```

Comment: Your format operator isn't really doing anything format-specific, so it may be easier read like so: `{ "$($_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value -replace ' ', '_').pdf" }`

Comment: I find mine to be easier to read and more straightforward than yours (also more .NET-like, as many readers here are familiar with .NET string formatting).

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that you know the line spacing is the same on each "polling station" line, you could just remove all of the spaces. Then trim off the irrelevant parts, then format your line with `substring()` methods.

```
$Text = 'constit uency: xxxyyyzzz

polling stat i on: abc de f ghi (00 1)

stream: 12 3'
$trimmed = $text -replace "\s",'' -replace '^.*pollingstation:','' -replace "stream:.*$",''
"$($trimmed.substring(0,3))_$($trimmed.substring(3,3))_$($trimmed.substring(6,3))_$($trimmed.substring(9,5)).pdf"

#Output: 'abc_def_ghi_(001).pdf'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the spacing is different in each text file because OCR is not very stable. So in this case, will I be able to put a wildcard * between every letter (ex- "s*t*r*e*a*m*:.*$"), or would there be a better way?

Comment: @SaewonPark The spacing being different in the input isn't the question, it's whether you can count on the spacing in the output format e.g. `abc def ghi (001)` or `qwe rty uio (123)`. If you can't, I doubt you'll be able to find a good solution.